# Turn jQuery's foo.css('opacity', '0') into foo.alpha = 0

Tags: jquery

I have a background in ActionScript and would like to make it easier to set some properties of objects. I'd like to have the ability to set an object's opacity shorthand like so:

```
foo.alpha = 0;
```

instead of

```
foo.css('opacity', '0')
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: This seems like an XY issue to me.

Comment: It may be possible to extend jquery to do this, but it seems like too much of a hassle.

Comment: When you learn a new language, embrace it. Don't try to bend it to match a different language.

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to turn a method into a property?

Comment: @Tom Maybe, but you'd have to know how jQuery works.  However, why don't you just use vanilla js for this?  `element.style.opacity = etc;`

Comment: I guess I'm more curious if anyone has tried something like this. It would be nice to shorthand certain methods into a property. But it's looking like it would be too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(function(){Object.defineProperty($.prototype, 'alpha',
    {set: function(value) {
        this.css('opacity', value);
    }});
});
```

Put this at the top of your document after jQuery to allow the syntax you describe. It can be extended to allow other properties to work this way. I can't guarantee its robustness, but it does seem to work. I recommend against using it, though. This code is likely to confuse even experienced JavaScript programmers. Like the other commenters, I agree that learning the style of a new language rather than trying to make it look like another language is generally a good idea.

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/aP4L9/

Comment: +1, hats off to you, I thought it'd be more complex than this.

Comment: I agree with not using something like this on production or within a team, but I was curious about techniques on extending jQuery or JS in some way. Thank you for this. I learned a lot from just a few lines!